# loki: reinstall the cups package

Tags: printer

Me: total noob. Experience: unix system and network manager 30 years ago. Have not used unix or linux since then. Installed loki a couple weeks ago on an old PC box.  A few days ago my printers disappeared.  Canon 922 wireless was working before that.  Tried to reconfigure cups but got msg that cups was broken or not installed.  purged cups and configuration files.  Now I don't know how to reinstall cups. What commands do I use to reinstall cups?

My canon 922 still works on my PC notebook with loki installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can (re)install `cups` with

```
sudo apt install cups
```